# JavaScript array reduce to sum lengths of sub-arrays - why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, reduce

I'm not getting expected results when trying this `reduce` in JavaScript:

```
let x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

x.reduce((a,b) => a.length + b.length, []);
```

Simple, right? Here's what I expect to happen, step-by-step:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| callback | a (accumulator) | b (currentValue) | return value |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1st run  | 0               | 3                | 3            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2nd run  | 3               | 3                | 6            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2nd run  | 6               | 3                | 9            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

What do I actually get? `NaN`. In english, if I understand things correctly, the iterator first looks at the initial value I give it (the empty array as the 2nd argument to `reduce`) and that is represented by the argument `a`. My code shows a simple `.length` on both arguments being added. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The inputs are arrays, not numbers, you're glossing over this in your chart. `a`'s first value is `[]`, not `0`, so `a.length` works. By returning a number, you're feeding a number into the next iteration, and invoking `.length` on it, which is obviously not your intention.

Comment: @meagar Yup, just realized that looking at Pointy's code below. Thank you!

Comment: If your intent is to sum the length of the arrays, you can `map` and `reduce` very cleanly: `x.map(a => a.length).reduce((a,b) => a + b)`

Comment: Walk though your code with a debugger, examining variables at each step.

Comment: @meager Your code will fail with an empty array--which one would expect to return zero.

Comment: I'd love to know why this was down-voted. Isn't SO the place to _ask_ questions so you can learn and find solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointy's code above (doesn't actually return 9 like intended) got me to this working solution:

```
let x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
x.reduce((a,b) => a + b.length, 0);
```

Meager also pointed out in the comments that this is a classic case for the `map/reduce` combo as such (a much sleeker solution):

```
let x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
x.map(a => a.length).reduce((a,b) => a + b);
```

Comment: `a` will never be array in reduce when you set the initial start value as zero and never return array from the callback See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Meager's solution is flawed, because it is missing an initial value and therefore fails if the array has no elements, even though that probably should be valid input returning zero.

Comment: @torazaburo I put the variable assignment in meager's solution to at least show its for this particular instance. But point taken.

Answer (score 18):

I think this is what you're trying to do (variables renamed for clarity):

```
let x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

x.reduce((acc,element) => acc + element.length, 0);
```

This is how it would happen step-by-step:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| callback | acc | element   | element.length | return value |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1st run  | 0   | [1, 2, 3] | 3              | 3            |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 2nd run  | 3   | [4, 5, 6] | 3              | 6            |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 3rd run  | 6   | [7, 8, 9] | 3              | 9            |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 8):

The `.reduce()` API expects that your callback function will return the accumulator value (in your case, the value that starts off as `[]`). Your callback just returns a value.

To make your code work, you'd need something like:

```
x.reduce((a,b) => { a.push(a.length + b.length); return a; }, []);
```

Now, if what you *really* want is a sum of the lengths of the arrays, then you don't want to accumulate into an array anyway; you want a simple sum. Instead of having the accumulator be an array then it just needs to be a number:

```
var sum = x.reduce(((sum, array) => sum + array.length), 0);
```

Start with zero, and each call to the function adds the array length to the sum.

Comment: @TheQodesmith just did :)

Comment: Ahh, I see. So in my case, since I'm accumulating array lengths, an array would need to be returned to continue iterating to be consistent.

Comment: Right. The `.reduce()` function requires that your callback returns the accumulator.

Comment: Just an FYI, that code won't actually return the complete length, it returns an array. But you got me to a working solution below. Thanks again.

Comment: But he wants to get `9`. this returns `[3,4,5]` which I don't think means anything at all.

Comment: @torazaburo yes, I was just fixing the original code. To get what the OP actually wants it would have to be different in fairly obvious ways; I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using `reduce`, flatten the array and take the length of the result.

```js
function flatten(a) { return [].concat(...a); }

const x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
const length = flatten(x).length;

console.log(length);
```

The implementation of `flatten` above is for arrays which have depth of one or two. Extend/replace it as necessary for more deeply nested arrays.